# How to do Alfresco Using Alfresco Web Service

Tags: java, web-services, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

i am working in a IT Company and i need to learn Alfresco. Using Apache CMIS i am able to all operations like Creating Folder, Creating Document, Creating Link of Folder and Document and blah blah.
Now I need to do all the operation using alfresco own web service.
I did google a lot but not able to get a single link over that.
**Can any body suggest link or contents from where i can do all the operations using Alfresco own webservice**. Document is good but i have less time and i cannot go through the whole document.
It will be helpful if i can get an example build on maven(java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking how to use Alfresco via a SOAP-based web service, that no longer exists.

If you are asking how to use Alfresco's native REST API, then you could start by looking at https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/.

If you need to write your own RESTful endpoints in Alfresco that you will then call remotely, you can read my tutorial on Web Scripts: http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/webscripts/tutorial/tutorial.html.

Comment: Thank you Jeff, you have provided enough  good links to start.